# Export table to excel table

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hi I'm trying to export a table present in a site, when I open the csv file I find myself exported only the first row and in the execution of the code it returns me

> cannot set a row with mismatched columns

the code:

```
from curses import color_content
from email import header
from lib2to3.pgen2.token import COLONEQUAL
from wsgiref import headers
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

#page to access 
url = 'site.xxx'

#request.get

page = requests.get(url)

#beatifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

#extract table

table1=soup.find('table',id='table28')

#extract column

headers = []
for i in table1.find_all('th'):
   title = i.text
   headers.append(title)

#create dataframe

mydata=pd.DataFrame(columns=headers)

# Create a for loop to fill mydata
for j in table1.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    row_data = j.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in row_data]
    length = len(mydata)
    mydata.loc[length] = row



# Export to csv
mydata.to_csv('classifica_piloti2.csv', index=False)# Try to read csv
mydata2 = pd.read_csv('classifica_piloti2.csv')
```

Comment: Have you printed this data to see what you are getting?  My guess is that the `<tr>` columns don't match the `<th>` headers.

Comment: @TimRoberts if I try to print "mydata" it returns me all the columns without the rows and if I try to print "raw_data" it returns me all the html code only if it is inside the for

Comment: `pandas` has a `read_html` function that convert a `<table>` to a dataframe directly.  That might be your least-cost solution.